# Implementing an OnClick method for a custom ActionBar button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have an Activity that's associated with a layout as usual, using:

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_precode_checklist);
```

However, this activity uses a custom action bar which has it's own separate layout, using:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.precode_checklist_actionbar);
```

Inside of the `layout.precode_checklist_actionbar` I have a button element with an onClick method called `toMainMenu`. My problem is that when I try to implement that method in my Activity class I get the error:

```
Could not find a method toMainMenu(View) in the activity class   android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button
```

Implementation:

```
public void toMainMenu(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because of `android.view.ContextThemeWrapper` is used for the inflated view, not activity. Try

```
setCustomView(...);
getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.button).setOnclickListener(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, check out the comment on @Chris.Zou

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use

```
getActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.your_button_id).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentAcivity.this, MainMenu.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}});
```

After you call `getActionBar().setCustomView(...)`

Comment: I get the errror:
`Error:(25, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnClickListener>,Class<MainMenu>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)`


On the line `Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class)`

Comment: Fixed it using `Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainMenu.class);`

Comment: @Brejuro Fixed your problem, replace `YourCurrentAcivity` with the Activity name you are currently in. But your approach works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Give **android:onClick="clickEvent"** in .xml file

```
public void clickEvent(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you click on button1",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you click on button2",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

}